# Is it possible to change .Xresources interactively?

Tags: xserver

What I have in mind is something like:

```
#include $PATH_TO_FILE
```

in .Xresources, so that I could change the value of PATH_TO_FILE and run `xrdb -merge`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it can't. What one *can* do is `#include /path/to/symlink` and then use `PATH_TO_FILE` in a script to change the file that `symlink` points to.